# Spider error processing scrapy when trying to fetch any url

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

So I am new to Scrapy and when i try to fetch any url in scrapy shell, i'll get this error. I have Scrapy installed in a virtual env.

```
>>> fetch('https://www.digikala.com/')
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 140718217880064 on /home/ariyan/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__venv__63b271__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 140718217880064 acquired on /home/ariyan/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__venv__63b271__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 140718217880064 on /home/ariyan/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__venv__63b271__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 140718217880064 released on /home/ariyan/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__venv__63b271__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/> (referer: None)
>>> 2023-01-30 14:45:55 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.digikala.com/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ariyan/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/ariyan/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 285, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "/home/ariyan/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 272, in deferred_from_coro
    event_loop = get_asyncio_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (start)'.
2023-01-30 14:45:55 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/ariyan/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:892: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SpiderMiddlewareManager.scrape_response.<locals>.process_callback_output' was never awaited
  current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
```

Comment: thanks for the error, but please post the code. the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sounds like there is something funky with your scrapy version or installation  try there was a bug in scrapy 2.6 i think that caused this.  but it has since been patched  `pip install -U --force-reinstall scrapy`

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed to fix it by installing an older version of scrapy(2.6.0).

```
pip3 install scrapy=={version}
```